# Why is 'a operator= b' relatively a little faster than 'a = a operator b' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I have read this statement in a book called "Programming in Python 3", by Mark Summerfield. This statement doesn't make a lot of sense to me. So can you help me to resolve this little but important statement?

> The augmented version looks up a’s value only once,so it is potentially faster.

Chapter 1 "Python's Beautiful Heart", #6 Arithmetic Operators, p31, 4th last line

Comment: Please give a specific, referenced (at least title *and author*, but ideally also chapter/page/location) quote, using the `>` markdown format, and clarify what your question is about that. Also note not all potential answered identify as "guys".

Comment: Guys is gender-neutral

Comment: @AlecAlameddine not to everybody

Comment: Well if someone likes writing "guys" instead of "guys and girls/gals" they have every right to, and "guys" is generally accepted as neutral anyways. Focusing on that is pedantry which not good for SO

Comment: @AlecAlameddine if it's unimportant pedantry, so is your counterclaim; why did you get involved? What you're actually saying by "guys is gender neutral" is "I don't feel excluded by guys, *and nobody else should either*". Well, some people *do* (also by e.g. "guys and gals", for what it's worth). So, with that information, you can either: 1. stop using it as if nobody felt excluded by it; or 2. be deliberately exclusionary. That's up to you.

Comment: I hope, now you are willing to answer @jonrsharpe ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe edit it if you care so much. pedantry is toxic to new users trying to learn the rules that actually matter.

Comment: yes I'm a new user here , @AlecAlameddine. Did I say something wrong ?

Comment: Not in my view. Jon disagrees.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice) provides a good explanation on why the assignment  `i=i+1` is slightly slower than `i+=1`
Basically, they correspond at low level to a different way of working of the processor.

Comment: Thanks, it does makes a lot sense now,I totally forgot about the low level.

Comment: At first sight the preceding statements are unsurprising,particularly to those
familiar with C-like languages. In such languages, augmented assignment is
shorthand for assigning the results of an operation—for example, a += 8 is essentially the same as a = a + 8 .However,there are two important subtleties here,

Comment: with int , what actually happens behind the scenes when an augmented assignment operator is used on an
immutable object is that the operation is performed,and an object holding the
result is created;and then the target object reference is rebound to refer to the
result object rather than the object it referred to before.

Comment: The second subtlety is that a operator= b is not quite the same as a = a operator
b .The augmented version looks up a ’s value only once,so it is potentially faster.

Comment: The above two statements were written in the book.That means that it has something different then C like languages. @Piakkaa

Comment: yeah because it looks up the value only once instead of twice. Curious to know how much difference it makes though. My guess is below 0.1%